# Improving code to generate a distribution

Tags: haskell, statistics

I am new to Haskell and I wonder how/if I can make this code more efficient and tidy. It seems unnecessarily long and untidy.

My script generates a list of 10 averages of 10 coin flips.

```
import Data.List
import System.Random

type Rand a = StdGen -> Maybe (a,StdGen)

output = do
    gen <- newStdGen
    return $ distBernoulli 10 10 gen

distBernoulli :: Int -> Int -> StdGen -> [Double]
distBernoulli m n gen = [fromIntegral (sum x) / fromIntegral (length x) | x <- lst]
    where lst = splitList (randomList (n*m) gen) n

splitList :: [Int] -> Int -> [[Int]]
splitList [] n = []
splitList lst n = take n lst : splitList (drop n lst) n

randomList :: Int -> StdGen -> [Int]
randomList n = take n . unfoldr trialBernoulli

trialBernoulli :: Rand Int
trialBernoulli gen = Just ((2*x)-1,y)
                 where (x,y) = randomR (0,1) gen
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd tackle this problem in a slightly different way. First I'd define a function that would give me an infinite sampling of flips from a Bernoulli distribution with success probability `p`:

```
flips :: Double -> StdGen -> [Bool]
flips p = map (< p) . randoms
```

Then I'd write `distBernoulli` as follows:

```
distBernoulli :: Int -> Int -> StdGen -> [Double]
distBernoulli m n = take m . map avg . splitEvery n . map val . flips 0.5
  where
    val True = 1
    val False = -1
    avg = (/ fromIntegral n) . sum
```

I think this matches your definition of `distBernoulli`:

```
*Main> distBernoulli 10 10 $ mkStdGen 0
[-0.2,0.4,0.4,0.0,0.0,0.2,0.0,0.6,0.2,0.0]
```

(Note that I'm using `splitEvery` from the handy [split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split) package, so you'd have to install the package and add `import Data.List.Split (splitEvery)` to your imports.)

This approach is slightly more general, and I think a little neater, but really the main difference is just that I'm using `randoms` and `splitEvery`.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I posted this too fast and didn't match behavior, it should be good now.

```
import Control.Monad.Random
import Control.Monad (liftM, replicateM)
```

KNOWLEDGE: If you like randoms then use [MonadRandom](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom) - it rocks.

STYLE: Only importing symbols you use helps readability and sometimes maintainability.

```
output :: IO [Double]
output = liftM (map dist) getLists
```

Note: I've given output an explicit type, but know it doesn't *have* to be IO.

STYLE:

1) Its usually good to separate your IO from pure functions.  Here I've divided out the getting of random lists from the calculation of distributions.  In your case it was pure but you combined getting "random" lists via a generator with the distribution function; I would divide those parts up.

2) Read [Do notation considered harmful](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Do_notation_considered_harmful).  Consider using `>>=` instead of

```
output = do
   gen <- new
   return $ dist gen
```

you can do:

```
output = new >>= dist
```

Wow!

```
dist :: [Int] -> Double
dist lst = (fromIntegral (sum lst) / fromIntegral (length lst))

getLists :: MonadRandom m => Int -> Int -> m [[Int]]
getLists m n= replicateM m (getList n)
```

KNOWLEDGE In [Control.Monad](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12-latest/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Control-Monad.html) anything ending in an `M` is like the original but for monads.  In this case, `replicateM` should be familiar if you used the Data.List `replicate` function.

```
getList :: MonadRandom m => Int -> m [Int]
getList m = liftM (map (subtract 1 . (*2)) . take m) (getRandomRs (0,1::Int))
```

STYLE: If I do something lots of times I like to have a single instance in its own function (getList) then the repetition in a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your code or your question...

But it seems to me all you'd need to do is generate a list of random ones and zeroes, and then divide each of them by their length with a `map` and add them together with a `foldl`.

Something like:

makeList n lis = if n /= 0 then 
makeList (n-1) randomR(0,1) : lis
else
lis

And then make it apply a Map and Foldl or Foldr to it.

Comment: sorry, i did explain badly. i am basically trying to create the data to build the standard normal distribution. by virtually flipping a coin (with result 1 or -1) 10 times, and taking the average of the result, we get say -0.2. by doing this process say 1000 times, we can plot the results and their frequency and obtain the normal distribution. i am trying to create a list of doubles that i can plot to draw this distribution.

Comment: to clarify, the result of this script could be [0.2,0.0,0.0,-0.4,0.6,0.0,-0.2,0.2,0.4,0.0]

Answer (score 0):

Using the above, I am now using this.

```
import Data.List
import System.Random

type Rand a = [a]

distBernoulli :: Int -> Int -> StdGen -> [Double]
distBernoulli m n gen = [fromIntegral (sum x) / fromIntegral (length x) | x <- lst]
    where lst = take m $ splitList (listBernoulli gen) n

listBernoulli :: StdGen -> Rand Int
listBernoulli = map (\x -> (x*2)-1) . randomRs (0,1)

splitList :: [Int] -> Int -> [[Int]]
splitList lst n = take n lst : splitList (drop n lst) n
```

Thanks for your help, and I welcome any further comments :)